# Strophe JS cannot connect to xmmp MongooseIm server in ionic4/Angular 8 hybrid app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, xmpp, strophe, mongoose-im

I am currently developing a chat application using MongooseIm Xmpp server and strophe based client in an hybrid Ionic4/Angular 8 application.

I am able to connect via web and devapp but on installing the exported apk the client connection times out and i cannot connect to the xmpp server.

I get Connection timeout or connection fail.

below is how i make the connection:
(the actual url in the mobile app is mongooseIm instance on aws)

```
  this.xmppConnection = new Strophe.Connection('http://localhost.com:5280/http-bind');
  this.xmppConnection.connect(
    jid + '@' + this.host,
    password,
    this.onConnect
  );
```

OnConnect Handler:

```
private onConnect(status: any): void {
switch (status) {
  case Strophe.Status.CONNECTING:
    alert('Connecting to xmpp...');
    break;
  case Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL:
    alert('xmpp connection failed!');
    break;
  case Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTING:
    alert('Disconnecting from xmpp...');
    break;
  case Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED:
    alert('Disconnected from xmpp');
    break;
  case Strophe.Status.CONNECTED:
    alert('xmpp connected!');
    break;
  case Strophe.Status.AUTHENTICATING:
    alert('xmpp authenticating...');
    break;
  case Strophe.Status.AUTHFAIL:
    alert('xmpp authentication failed!');
    break;
  case Strophe.Status.ERROR:
    alert('xmpp generic connection error!');
    break;
  case Strophe.Status.ATTACHED:
    alert('xmpp connection attached!');
    break;
  case Strophe.Status.REDIRECT:
    alert('xmpp connection redirected!');
    break;
  case Strophe.Status.CONNTIMEOUT:
    alert('xmpp connection timeout!');
    break;
  default:
    alert('xmpp: Unknow connection status');
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated.